# How to convert Array of string to Array of URL?

Tags: swift

Need to convert array of string value to array of URL. Some one help me to convert the String array to URL array in swift.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
let urls = ["www.1.com", "www.1.com", "www.1.com", "randomSmth"].compactMap { URL(string: $0) }
```

"compactMap" ensures that it just ignores invalid urls.

Comment: Upvoting your answer because you were the first to provide a valid solution that didn't include force unwrapping (a ton of duplicates just appeared). This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use compact map to filter non valid URLs

```
let arrayOfStrings = ["https://www.google.com","https://www.facebook.com", "notRerallyAnURL"]
let arrayOfURLs = arrayOfStrings.compactMap { URL(string:$0) }
```